# Spring application modularity

Tags: java, spring, maven, modularity

I have a web application, which will be installed in multiple companies. Each of companies have API, which I try to unify and put in separate modules. (It's a security reason, as I don't want `CompanyA` to have `CompanyB`'s API).

So, I think it should be something like this (btw I use Maven),

**`external-api`** module, which has only interfaces for API, something like:

```
interface ExternalApi {
    ....
}
```

**`main-application`** module, which depends on **`external-api`** and Inject's it's implementation:

```
@RestController
class ApiController {

    @Inject
    ExternalApi api;

    ...

}
```

and lots of modules, like
**`companyA-external-api`** (also depends on **`external-api`**) with `ExternalApi` interface implementation:

```
@Service
class CompanyAExternalApi implements ExternalApi {
    ....
}
```

Now, as I understand, I can put external api module's output jars under application's classpath and have it classes loaded and processed by Spring.

Is this a legitimate way? Or should it be done in more automatic way (maybe there are some Maven plugins or Gradle scripts), because I'm feeling like reinventing the wheel?

Comment: So you publish a module of interfaces called **external-api**, having each company implement the interfaces. Also, you supply web access module called **main-application** that only knows **external-api**, right? That sounds simple and nicely de-coupled. The only issue I can suggest is that the web access module should better be called something like **web-api**. The main application is actually what your customers are implementing.